# Arithmetic in java

Tags: java

I have the following homework problem:

> Write an application integer on that
>   reads an integer and determines and
>   prints whether it is odd or even.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: should be tagged as homework. i%2==0

Comment: It's a homework, isn't it? And maybe you should show what you've done so far.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, and probably should be tagged as such. As a rule, the community gives hints on homework questions only when you've shown sufficient effort to attempt to solve the problem first.

Answer (score 12):

Use the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for reading input.

Store that input into an integer. Check if input is really a valid integer. Otherwise, throw an exception.

Afterwards, use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls) to check if it's odd or even.

Use [System.out.println](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) to print if it's odd or even.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I didn't really solve it; I just gave a description of what to do. OP must gather the pieces to solve the puzzle. Writing the actual code would be solving his homework.

Comment: +1. @Elite I think @darioo answered exactly the way one should, concerning homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter number");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {

        int i = sc.nextInt();
        if (Math.abs(i) / i == 1) {
            if ((Math.abs(i) % 2) == 0) {
                System.out.println("Even");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Odd");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + ex.toString());
    }

}
```